# which statistical test should be used in the scenario?

Tags: statistics, spss

I am currently trying to analyze some data, and would rather have some statistical analyzes rather than trying to eye-ball patterns and differences. However, I am new to statistics and SPSS and therefore am unsure on which test should be used.

Basically, I have the averages of a trade area for 30 variables. These are already averaged out so basically I have the variable names in one column, followed by the variable averages of all trade area in 2001, then the averages in 2011 and 2016.

With this data I want to see how the trade areas have change -- in have they changed significantly or not over time. Which test would be best suited through SPSS?

Cheers

Comment: Don't worry about conventional statistics tests (by which I assume you mean significance tests on p-values). Such tests are useless and misleading. Instead work on quantifying how the variables have changed over time. By the way, you'll get more interest in this topic at stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in spss, but the problem requires looking at which areas are of significance. For this, statistically one needs to look at using the ANOVA or Analysis of Variance.

You may find [this](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/one-way-anova-using-spss-statistics.php) link useful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your description that your data looks like this:

```
trade_area | 2001 | 2011 | 2016
-------------------------------
area1.     | 30   | 40   | 45
area2.     | 22   | 16   | 36
area3.     | 44   | 45   | 36
...
```

If you can't aggregate all the trade areas (i.e. treat them all as a single entity), then you can, at most, say something like: in area 1, the values for 2016 and 2011 are more than the values in 2001, because 40 > 30 and 45 > 30. The reason why you can't say anymore than that is because it's hard to justify a trend with only 3 data points.

Otherwise, if you have reason to treat all the areas as one entity (maybe an aggregate area), you can conduct a two-sided t-test with the inputs: 2011 vs. 2001 and 2016 vs. 2001, and maybe 2016 vs. 2011 if you like. This will allow you to say something like: the average of all trade area values in 2011 is significantly (or not) different to the average of all trade area values in 2001.